# Insert .jpg image in html web page

Tags: html, image

I am designing a web page in html language. At some point I have to insert a .jpg image that I downloaded from the net.
I saved the image on my desktop. Then, I insert it into the web page this way:

```
<img src = "image.jpg">
```

The image doesn't appear. But a default icon appears in its place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the image within the same folder as your **HTML** file.

If you're going to be using images on your site - the images must be somewhere within the directory of your current **HTML** file.

For example,

**Root Directory**
|
index.html
   **Images**
   |
image.jpg

Then within your `index.html` file, you would have:

```
<img src="images/image.jpg">
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>

    <img src='image.jpg'>

</body>
```

If you want this could work, you must put image.jpg and your html into the same directory.